# How to compile Qt app writen in Linux on Windows with mingw?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I've writen a Qt app with Qt5.15.2 on linux (Rhel8),but when i try to compile this app on a Windows 10 machine under Qt creator i got a bunch of error like :

```
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++\bits\fs_path.h:237: erreur : no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' and 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path')
In file included from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/filesystem:37,
                 from C:/Users/brd.LAPTOP-716I0O3B/Documents/app/AGM_COMPTA/datab.cpp:4:
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h: In member function 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path& std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::operator/=(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&)':
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:237:47: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' and 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path')
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is what i've done to import my project on Windows machine:

In Qt creator i chose File->Open file or project and choose my CMakeLists.txt
and i got this warning
[image: Qt creator warning]

then Qt creator ask me to configure the project, i just tick the MinGW 64 bits and continue:
[image: Qt creator project configuration]

Now the project is open, but when hit compile i got bunch of error:
[image: Compilation errors]

here is my CMakeLists.txt, i've two library build as subproject (SQLiteCpp and OpenXLSX):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(AGM_COMPTA VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


add_subdirectory(static_lib/SQLiteCpp)
add_subdirectory(static_lib/OpenXLSX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core console)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}Sql  REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Network REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
        dialogdocumentline.h
        dialogdocumentline.cpp
        dialogdocumentline.ui
        settingdialog.h settingdialog.cpp settingdialog.ui
        operationassociationdialog.h
        operationassociationdialog.cpp
        operationassociationdialog.ui
        dialogcashboxline.h
        dialogcashboxline.cpp
        dialogcashboxline.ui
        ressources.qrc
        datab.cpp datab.h Importer.cpp Importer.h OperationLine.h QStyledItemDelegateNoElide.h tools.h DocumentLine.h CashboxLine.h exportTools.h)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(AGM_COMPTA
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET AGM_COMPTA APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(AGM_COMPTA SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(AGM_COMPTA
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(AGM_COMPTA PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Sql SQLiteCpp sqlite3 OpenXLSX::OpenXLSX Qt5::Network OpenSSL::SSL stdc++fs)

set_target_properties(AGM_COMPTA PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(AGM_COMPTA)
endif()
```

i've tried to create a new basic project from Qt creator and it's working just fine.

**What could be wrong, and what should i do to narrow down search to find the error?**

Comment: TL;DR: Update your MinGW

Comment: What is in the `CMakeLists.txt.user` file? linux specific settings?

Comment: @ChrisMM commenting the <filesystem> include and all it's usage is working, so i switched to msvc compiler and <filesystem> and everything is working. i will keep using Microsoft compiler since i'm now targeting windows only. i've not tried to upgrade MinGW but i think it will work too. So, yes it's answer my question.